# Proving that $V$ and $V^*$ are not naturally isomorphic

Tags: linear-algebra, duality-theorems, dual-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

I'm comfortable with the idea that a vector space $V$ and its double-dual $V^{**}$ are *naturally isomorphic*, independent of bases:
$$
\Phi:V \to V^{**}, \quad v \mapsto \hat{v}
$$
$$
\quad \big( \Phi(v) \big)(f) = \hat{v}\,(f) = f(v)
$$
$$
\forall f\in V^*, \forall v\in V
$$

It is unclear to me, however, why $V$ and $V^*$ are not naturally isomorphic. It's clear that they can be made "unnaturally" isomorphic (if you will) by choosing a particular set of bases and cooking up the trivial isomorphism between these two sets. What is less clear is why there **cannot** be a natural isomorphism between them.

Is this some kind of category theoretic result? It seems proving that no natural isomorphism could ever exist is a much taller order than showing one *particular* isomorphism does exist. Any thoughts?